# PayPal Smart Button Debit or Credit Card Functionality- Display Amount

Tags: paypal

We recently added PayPals Smart Buttons to our website and hid or deactivated the PayPal Credit button so that only the blue PayPal and the black Debit or Credit Card remain. When a user pays by clicking on the PayPal button, the user can log onto PayPal or select Pay with Debit or Credit Card (as a Guest Checkout). In both situations, PayPal displays the amount being charged in the upper righthand corner of a new window.

When a user clicks on the black Debit or Credit Card, rather than open into a new window, PayPal expands embedded fields right in the website itself (which is pretty cool).  However, on our configuration it doesn't display the amount being charged.  While we display the amount charged in other places in our website, depending on the size of the users' screens, they often have to scroll up to view such amount.

I'm trying to figure out how to display the amount PayPal will charge if a user clicks on the black Debit or Credit Card (similar to how PayPal displays such amount when the blue PayPal button is selected). PayPal has this information which we display after payment with a pop-up message (and via a follow-up receipt sent by email), but it would give a customer confidence to see something official from PayPal contemporaneously as they click "Pay Now" (especially if the price we've listed isn't viewable because of screen size).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The black "Debit or Credit" card button expands inline with the rest of your web page, rather than opening a new window. Since it expands credit card fields inline on your page, it is designed to use minimal space on your page.

There is no option for PayPal to display the amount being charged. Since all this is happening on your page, you can display the amount yourself -- right there, wherever you want to show it. It's your page and you have full control over it.

Comment: What if I want to display the amount in the customer's local currency?

Comment: Paypal already show it using local currency, but the user must fill the card details first. Is there anyway to show it from beginning?

Comment: No. Those amounts only show when a currency conversion is happening at PayPal, so the user is informed about this, and PayPal only knows what local currency to show after the payer has filled in their card details (not before; there is nothing PayPal can know to show before that local card is entered).  To display the nominal amount you are receiving in the non-local PayPal-supported currency (e.g. USD or EUR), you must do this yourself with your own page HTML. PayPal won't do it for you.

Comment: Remember that if creating the order on the client side, you can use something like `value: document.getElementById(.....).value` or any other variable/function reference. The createOrder function is only called when a button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks Preston PHX, but why PayPal does not display the local currency based on the geographical information or the client local settings?